# In Google Chrome, how do I get the body content's height to grow depending on the content just like it behaves in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Here's my code:

```
body{
    color:#666;
    margin:0px;
    background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top,  color-stop(0.25, #DCDCDC), color-stop(0.75, #FFFFFF));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, #DCDCDC 25%,#FFFFFF 75%);
    font:13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

The effect I'm trying to do is a gradient from top (white) to bottom (gray) but the end of the bottom gradient should stop at the end of the content. So for example if the page's content is smaller than the window the gradient should stop at the bottom of that content not the bottom of the page. This example works on Firefox 3+ but in google chrome the height of the body is set to automatically cover 100% of the height of the window.

Any ideas? I don't really want to change the structure because I'm using HTML5 elements.

Here's a sample of the HTML: (I stripped the content due to company restrictions)

```
<html>
    <head>
        ... header here ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            ...header content here...
        </header>
        <article>
            ...body content here...
        </article>
        <footer>
            ...footer content here...
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you include the `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration at the beginning of your document?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce with webkit:

http://jsfiddle.net/2AwbB/

But I've seen that the background is repeating, perhaps you need:

```
background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top,  color-stop(0.25, #DCDCDC), color-stop(0.75, #FFFFFF));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm your code looks just like mine. Anyways I see this only occurs in Google Chrome. I haven't tried Webkit or Safari. Oh and BTW I'm using Google Chrome 9.0.597.47 beta.

Comment: You should be making a comment and not answering your own post like this.